# Site security regex handler? (PHP)

Tags: php, session, mod-rewrite, redirect, authentication

A company that I am working for asked me take one of their websites and make it a subdomain of another website. Then, they asked me to extend the "logged in/logged out" session control from their primary domain to their subdomain.

Having done this, I see that there are control/administration issues. Because of their vast number of individual pages, and because of their extensive directory structure, it is too involved for them to add a PHP snippet to each of their pages to redirect based on logged-in-status.

Here is my solution..please let me know of any problems or anything else that would help me along.

1. I am going to use Mod_rewrite to redirect every request on the subdomin to a specific page (**handler.php?requested_url=**).
2. I am going to make a "Site allow/forbid rules" section on their website. This section will contain one textbox with rules like this:

   ```
    +/weather/            ---> will allow anyone access to any url that contains "/weather/" somewhere within it, irregardless of logged-in status.

    -/weather/premium/    ---> will only allow access to a url that contains /weather/premium to logged-in users.
   ```

   This will output to an array  stored in a file **rules.php** which will look like this:

   ```
   $ruleList = array(); 
   $ruleList[] = '+/weather/'; 
   $ruleList[] = '-/weather/premium/';
   ```
3. In **handler.php**, If the user is logged in I will forward them to the **requested.url**. If the user is not logged in, then I will begin by assuming that every page is restricted to non-logged in users. **handler.php** will parse the **requested_url** and check it against **rules.php**, to see if there are any explicit permissions set. Then if the rule allows non-logged-in access, it will forward the user to the **requested_url**, otherwise it will send them to the login page.

One problem I can see immediately, is that given that the `Mod_rewrite` rule will send every request to **handler.php**, how do I avoid an infinite loop?

Should the redirection be done by some method other than `header("Location: ")`?

## **Edit: Here is an update to my struggle:**

Inside the **.htaccess** file of the top domain (example.com) I added:

```
    #Prevent catching requests for the sub1 subdomain
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sub1\.example\.com
    RewriteRule .* – [L]
```

---

Then, inside the **.htaccess** for the **sub1.example.com** subdomain, I added the following:

```
    IndexIgnore *

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /path/to/base

    #Avoid infinite loop on outgoing requests
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^/?handler.php?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?handler.php?$



        #Check for cookie. Redirect to handler if not found.  (not yet implemented)                               
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !session_id
    RewriteRule (.*)$ handler.php?requested_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

---

Here is **handler.php**

```
    <?php

        $url = $_REQUEST['requested_url'];

        //Check list of permissions. For now just assume permitted.
        $permitted = true;
        if ($url == "") $url = "http://sub1.example.com";   
        if ($permitted)
            header("Location: ".$url);
        header("Location: http://sub1.example.com");        

    ?>
```

I am so close I can taste it. Unfortunately for the time being I am getting a "redirect loop" almost everywhere. If someone could give me a nudge in the right direction, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: also check this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-secure-apps/index.html

Comment: As for "adding a snippet to every page being too involved", did you consider [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand your setup you should only get infinite redirect loops if the login page is classified as restricted access, right? So maybe your rule and URL parsing part does something unexpected?

Comment: You could try some tricky reverse proxy with this handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a loop in your idea, hence the loop in the application. Like this:

1. User-agent requests a legacy resource in the subdomain.
2. Since UA must have valid credentials and the legacy resource can't verify credentials, UA is redirected to handler.
3. Handler verifies credentials, and redirects UA back to legacy resource.
4. Go to 2.

The problem is that the requested resource cannot make a distinction between the UA's requests in steps 1 and 3, because the distinction is defined by the UA's credentials, which the legacy resource doesn't evaluate.

This contradiction is also apparent from another point of view. Imagine for a minute that you solve the loop and the UA is redirected to the legacy resource -- something like http://sub1.example.com/foo.php. For the server to return the resource, it would have to mean that the credentials were not evaluated (because it doesn't do that), and therefore that the resource is effectively public.

To get around this, you have to break the deadlock by changing the rules of either step 2 or 3:

- to change step 2, add credential evaluation to the response for the legacy resource. The previous answer suggesting `auto_prepend_file()` is headed in that direction, but only for PHP legacy files -- images, HTML, etc are out of luck.
- to change step 3, find a way to deliver the legacy resource without having the UA request the resource directly. One possibility is to have the handler obtain the resource from the file system and put it on the wire with `readfile()` and some HTTP header management.

Perhaps a combination of these will do the trick for you: `auto_prepend_file()` to apply authentication handling to legacy PHP, and `readfile()` for non-PHP content.

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea but perhaps you don't need to struggle with mod_rewrite. If you want to handle everything from PHP anyway why not to add a prepend file into your VHOST?

```
php_value auto_prepend_file handler.php
```

It will be included before any PHP script and you can redirect if required.

Comment: I think this solution makes a lot of sense. Your question proposed a really complicated solution and this one is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you don't want to use apache auth?  I think it would be a lot less complicated.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

You can specify access rules within a virtual host on a directory-by-directory basis, your user information can be in a flat file or database.

Comment: Lack of experience is probably the reason ;-)  I will take a look at this, thanks

Comment: After looking this over, the problem is that these directory access rules need to change dynamically based on input through an admin panel.

Comment: Hi Mike; how often do they change?  You could regenerate your apache config dynamically (and restart apache) when needed.

Comment: They change multiple times a day. I have considered regenerating apache configs dynamically, but that seems kinda hackish

Comment: Regenerating .htaccess files doesn't require an Apache2 restart.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple verification function. A user is either allowed to access a resource or not. So first of all setup the context:

```
$rules          = rules_load();
$uri            = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$userIsLoggedIn = user_is_logged_in();
```

Next to that we have the said validation function which by default should return `false` and takes the context as parameters:

```
$validation = function (array $rules, $uri, $userIsLoggedIn) {
    $permitted = false;    
    return $permitted;
};
```

The logic then is straight forward:

```
if ($validation($rules, $uri, $userIsLoggedIn)) {
    # can pass
    echo "can pass";
} else {
    # login first
    echo "login first";
}
```

Which naturally already gives you *"login first"*. Fine. We will change the parameters of that function soon. Let's see the how `$rules` and `$uri` stand to each other.

Each rule can match on a URI, at least the *path* can. Let's split the rule:

```
 <sign><path>

 sign    := [+-]
 path    := <segment>*/
 segment := /[a-z]+
```

A rule does or does not match the `$uri`. If it matches, the *sign* decides what this means.

So actually there are two groups specified by the *sign* and it can be said whether the `$uri` matches or not. This again is a simple function, first the array of rules is filtered by sign and then by path.

Consider a function with three input parameters that returns the subset of all rules in form of an array that do match with the uri:

```
function ($sign) use ($rules, $uri) {
    return array_reduce($rules, function ($a, $v) use ($rules, $sign, $uri) {
        $v[0] === $sign && false !== strpos($uri, substr($v, 1)) && $a[] = $v;
        return $a;
    }, array());
};
```

This is more or less a call to `array_reduce`. So let's assume this would be associated to a variable called `$match` which then can replace `$rules` and `$uri` as parameter for the `$validation` function.

```
$validation = function ($match, $userIsLoggedIn) {
```

So the part left over is to just formulate the validation conditions now:

```
    $permitted = $userIsLoggedIn;
```

By default, if the user is logged in, permission is granted. Only if the user is not logged in, we can grant permission if the - group is not matched and the + group is matched. The - group should come first and override any + rule for safety reasons:

```
    $permitted = $userIsLoggedIn ?: !$match('-') && $match('+');
```

The rest is to return that status:

```
    return $permitted;
};
```

As this function is rather trivial, we could emit it. The code now in full:

```
$rules          = rules_load();
$uri            = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$userIsLoggedIn = user_is_logged_in();

$match = rules_match($rules, $uri);

$permitted = $userIsLoggedIn ?: !$match('-') && $match('+');

if ($permitted) {
    # can pass
    echo "can pass";
} else {
    # login first
    echo "login first";
}

/**
 */
function rules_match(array $rules, $uri) {
    return function ($sign) use ($rules, $uri) {
        return array_reduce($rules, function ($a, $v) use ($rules, $sign, $uri) {
            $v[0] === $sign && false !== strpos($uri, substr($v, 1)) && $a[] = $v;
            return $a;
        }, array());
    };
}
```

Comment: And what is this answer?! Mike want to know about the redirect loop and you rewrite its rule check???

Comment: @BigBoss: Read the question thoroughly. These problems are inexistant the moment he puts his session check in there. unless he does not put it in, he will always have the loop problem. As the implementation is hidden, there is not much to answer. Mike wrote he'll implement that.